# Is it possible for a line of code that's not being called to cause a bug?

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, if-statement

I'm currently dealing with one of the strangest bugs I have ever seen. I have this "else if" statement and inside the else-if I have a line of code that is causing a bug to happen elsewhere (my program is kind of complicated so I don't think it would help to post a short snippet of code here because it would be too difficult to explain -- so I apologize in advance if this post seems rather vague).

The issue is that the line of code that is causing the bug is not being called at all. I put a break point at the line and also put a print statement before it but the program never enters that particular "if-else" statement. **The bug goes away when I comment out the line and shows up again when I uncomment it.** This leads me to believe that the line must be getting called somehow but my break point and prints suggest otherwise.

Has anyone ever heard of something like this happening? Why would a line of code that is not even being called affect the rest of my program? Are there other ways to detect if the line is being called somehow besides using breakpoints and print statements?

I'm using XCode as my IDE and this is a single threaded program (so it's not some weird asynchronous bug)

**PROBLEM HAS BEEN SOLVED. SEE TOP ANSWER**

Comment: Are you using the "if (condition) statement; else if (something else) statement; else statement;" syntax, without the braces?  Maybe when the line is commented out the *next* line is becoming dependent on the if/else if/else.

Comment: Tis too bad we can't see it (and thus will have at-best a random collection of WAGs as to what is causing it). If it truly is as you describe then you're likely invoking undefined behavior *somewhere* I'd say use Valgrind and start checking yourself, but your on a Mac, so you may need to step up with Instruments or something similar. Show the call and the relevant surrounding code in the function. it isn't likely to help, but it beats having *nothing* to go on. I'd also check for a semicolon after your `if(...);` <== there.

Comment: Nope, everything is encapsulated within braces

Comment: Copy and paste the if-else statement here. Even if we can't fully understand it, we may catch a syntax error that is causing this bug. If you do, be sure to copy and paste it, not retype it.

Comment: Since you happen to be using Xcode, maybe try the static analyzer, see if it notices anything.

Comment: As your question is vague, I ll just answer possible ways based on my assumption.  The code didn't compile when you uncomment the line because of unreachable code.

Comment: ^user3256147 can you elaborate? What do you mean wouldn't compile due to unreachable code?

Comment: When you comment out the code, it is changing the size of the program.  Do you have hardcoded constants or locations, or are you close to the top end of the size for your program space?  It could even be a bad pointer is writing past your program into a "safe" area when the code is commented, but when the code is present it is trashing the program.  Replace the code with some printfs or LED/GPIO toggles to confirm 100% that it is not being reached -- I've seen some debuggers fail to catch a breakpoint on poorly generated boot code.

Comment: If there is a case where the code is not getting executed at all in a loop for any condition, then that piece of code is not necessary for the program. In such a case you will get unreachable code error

Comment: Eg: if ( true){ exit(0); a++; print ("a is changed"); }

Comment: ^user3256147 i need that piece of code when I use a different set of command line arguments. For the arguments I'm currently using I don't need it

Comment: I have down-voted the question because the question is pretty much unanswerable with what we currently have. We are just shooting in the dark. If more information is provided and the question is brought to a point where users can give meaningful and reasonable answers the question, I will remove it.

Comment: Can you post that else if portion of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually may happen in some cases indeed and I already saw it before. If the bug is some slight buffer overflow then the presence/abasence of that line may make the compiler differently optimize the memory layout (ie. not allocate some variables or arrange them in a different way or place segments differently for example) that will by chance not trigger the problem anymore.

The same applies if the bug is a strange race condition: the lack of that line may change slightly the timings (due to differently optimized code) and make the bug come out.

Very long shot: that code may even somehow trigger a compiler bug. But this may be less the case, but it may.

So: yes it's definitely possible and I already saw it. And if something like this is happening to you and you're 100% sure your code is correct then be very careful since something quite nasty may be hiding in the code.

Comment: Thank you fede.evol. It did turn out that my some weird buffer issue that the compiler was overlooking wound up corrupting the memory of my entire program such that adding/removing completely unrelated lines of code altered the behavior of my program.

Answer (score 0):

Not that there is enough information here to really answer this question, but perhaps I can try to provide some pointers.

1. Optimization. Try turning it off if it is turned on at all. When the compiler is optimizing your code, it may make different decisions when a statement is present vs. when it isn't. Whenever I am dealing with bugs that go away when a a seemingly unrelated code construct is changed, it is usually that the optimizer is doing something differently. I suppose a very simple example would be if the statement accesses something that the compiler would otherwise think is never accessed and can be folded away. The "unrelated" line may take an address of something which affects aliasing information, etc. All this isn't to say that the optimizer is wrong, your code likely still does have a bug, but it just explains the weird behaviour.
2. Debugging. It is very unlikely that the bug is in this line that is not reached. What I would focus on is setting watch points for the variables that are getting incorrect values (assuming you can narrow it down to what is receiving the wrong value).

These very weird issues often indicate an uninitialized variable or something along those lines. If the underlying compiler supports it, you can try providing an option that will cause the program to trap when an uninitialized memory location is being accessed.

Finally, this could be an indication that something is overwriting areas of the stack (and perhaps less likely other memory areas - heap, data). If you have anything that is writing to arrays allocated on the stack, check if you're walking past the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using { and } around the bodies in your if() and else clauses. Without them it's easy to wind up with something like this:

```
if (a)
    do_a_work();
    if (b)
        do_a_and_b_work();
else
    do_not_a_work();
```

Which actually equates to this (and is not what's implied by the indenting):

```
if (a) {
    do_a_work();
}
if (b) {
    do_a_and_b_work();
} else {
    do_not_a_work();
}
```

because the brace-less if (a) only takes the first statement below it for its body.

Commenting out your mystery line may be changing which code belongs to which if-else.